# How do you call another ant target with parameters (-logger org.apache.tools.ant.listener.MailLogger) from another ant script?

Tags: email, ant, build, automated-deploy, automated-deployment

I have a main ant script, that is used to initiate multiple project's ant script, in a certain sequence.

For each sub-project, I would like to to send out an email, notifying me whether the build was successful or not.

I understand that I can use the flag -logger with `org.apache.tools.ant.listener.MailLogger` to send out an email after the build finishes.

However, if I have multiple scripts that I want to send out an email, I'm not sure how to pass that flag `-logger org.apache.tools.ant.listener.MailLogger` into the ant call.

Precisely, I would like to pass the logger flag into this ant call:

> < ant antfile="build.xml" dir="subproject/build" target="build" />

I tried using `param` and `args`, but didn't succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. Personally I could not make it work with the `ant` target. It seems flags are not supported.

However, this hack works.

```
<exec executable="ant.bat">
    <arg value="-logger"/>
    <arg value="org.apache.tools.ant.listener.MailLogger"/>
    <arg value="-f"/>
    <arg value="other_build.xml"/>
</exec>
```

Two immediate issues with this approach:

1. Not platform independent.
2. Build reports success when sub-build fails (even with exec's `failonerror='true'`)

Comment: I finally did this: ant target1 target2 -logger org.apache.tools.ant.listener.MailLogger, and then put it into a .bat file... almost the same solution as yours...